# how to run illustrate command in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I tried to run **illustrate command** on alias in pig in both local and hdfs mode also.
But i am getting below error.

> 2014-08-27 19:18:06,703 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator - Error reading data. Internal
>   error creating job configuration. java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal
>   error creating job configuration.
>         at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java:160)
>         at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1182)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:739)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:626)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:323)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
>         at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
>         at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208) 2014-08-27 19:18:06,707 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Exception Details at logfile: /opt/pig_1409147241095.log

I am running Illustrate command using this example.

Say the input file is 'visits.txt' containing the following data :

> Amy     cnn.com 20070218 Fred    harvard.edu     20071204 Amy
>   bbc.com 20071205 Fred    stanford.edu    20071206

A grunt session might look something like this (Note the use of schemas while loading data. ExampleGenerator needs you to provide aliases) :

```
grunt> visits = load 'visits.txt' as (user, url, timestamp);
grunt> recent_visits = filter visits by timestamp >= '20071201';
grunt> user_visits = group recent_visits by user;
grunt> num_user_visits = foreach user_visits generate group, COUNT(recent_visits);
grunt> illustrate num_user_visits
```

Comment: No that trick is not working. I changed my code as below still same error


`visits = load 'visits.txt' as (user, url);
user_visits = group visits by user;
illustrate user_visits`


I have executed very simple code here not any time or date variable.

Comment: can you paste the content of '/opt/pig_1409147241095.log' . Also are you able to dump 'visits' in grunt shell?

Answer (score 1):

set `pig.enable.plan.serialization=false` on `/etc/pig/conf/pig.properties`